# Accessing number of Industry types in ruby on rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In an app I'm building, the users can select different types of industries as they Sign up to the app.

The user selects its industry type by picking its industry from a dropdown selector.

this is in the `user.rb`model

```
 INDUSTRY_TYPES = YAML.load_file(Rails.root.join('config', 'industry_types.yml')).freeze
```

and here is the code in the `sign up`view

```
   <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :industry_type %>
    <%= f.select(:industry_type, options_for_select(User::INDUSTRY_TYPES)) %>
   </div>
```

Some users might be in Agriculture, some in steelworking, etc.

So I want to be able to display on the `index.html.erb` how many industry types the users are in, for example two users are in agriculture, and four in steelworking, so it would be  6 users in 2 different industries.

The industry_type gets saved to the database.

My question is basically how am I able to fetch those values from the database?

**update**
I've tried to add this `User.all.map(&:industry_type).count` to a variable, but it seems to just count everything.

I know how to display the industry type for each user, but it´s more complicated to get the total number for each industry.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Are you using PostgreSQL? If not, what RDMS are you using?

Comment: Yeah, I'm using postgreSQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
User.group(:industry_type).count
```

Which should return a Hash structured like:

```
{ "industry_type_1" => 1, "industry_type_1" => 2, "industry_type_1" => 3 }
```

If "industry_type_2" is not associated to any User, it won't be in that Hash. In other words, `User.where(id: -1).group(:industry_type).count` returns an empty Hash.

Display the result:

```
# haml
- User.group(:industry_type).count.each do |industry_type, count|
  = "The Industry '#{industry_type}' has #{count} User(s)"
```

Comment: ok thank you @MrYoshiji, can you see my edit, is that different from ´User.all.map(&:industry_type).count´?

Comment: `User.all.map(&:industry_type)` returns the value of `industry_type` attribute for each User of the scope, and then you `count` them. So this is basically counting the users.

Comment: Ok I get it, but this will then probably display the whole Hash in the view? like `User.group(:industry_type).count
   (3.7ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, industry_type AS industry_type FROM "users" GROUP BY "users"."industry_type"
=> {nil=>1, "Medium"=>1, "Heavy"=>3, "Farming"=>1, "Fishery"=>2, "Light"=>1, "Dirty"=>1}
`

Comment: Well I assume that you know how to loop through a Hash and display its key/value. Do you want me to show you how to do this?

Comment: I've an idea about it but it would be nice to show how a professional does it.

Comment: @DaudiHell using SQLmethods like `group` through ActiveRecord is more performant than doing it via Ruby methods like `map`. It also requires less data to be loaded into memory. For example if you have a million records then evaluating `User.all` might not be usable. Although keep in mind that ActiveRecords are chainable, so `User.group(...)` is the same as `User.all.group(...)`, it just depends on when you evaluate the query into an array (via `map`, `to_a`, `each`, `[]`, etc)

Comment: It's somehow not working in my view `<% User.group(:industry_type).count.each do |industry_type, count| %>
    <%=The Industry '#{industry_type}' has '#{count} User' %>
    <% end %>`

Comment: I need more information to help you on that error. Is there an error that was raised? Is it outputting something? What is the issue here?

Comment: this is the error `/index.html.erb:16: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting ')' ...Industry '#{industry_type}' has '#{count} User' );@output_bu... ... ^`

Comment: @DaudiHell you did not wrap the output with a double quote, use this: `<%= "The Industry '#{industry_type}' has '#{count} User'" %>`

Comment: this is working but now the output is like this `The Industry '' has '1 User' The Industry 'Medium' has '1 User' The Industry 'Heavy' has '3 User' The Industry 'Farming' has '1 User' The Industry 'Fishery' has '2 User' The Industry 'Light' has '1 User' The Industry 'Dirty' has '1 User'`

Comment: This is normal. I did this very simple loop to show you how you can interpolate the key/value pairs to variables and access them. From now, it is up to you how you want to display this information. Take a look at some Rails tutorials if you need. Also, from the output, there is 1 User which has no `industry_type` filled (to find him back, run `User.where(industry_type: nil)`)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like `User.group(:industry_type).count` ?